# Filtering logic for an array of object based on tabs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have 3 tabs tabA, tabB, tabC and I have a common array of object  which is being displayed in all these 3 tabs i.e

```
`    data=[{value:"someValue (tabA) RO"},{value:"someValue (tabA) RW" },
           {value:"someValue (tabB) RO"},{value:"someValue (tabB) RW" } , 
           {value:"someValue (tabC) RO"},{value:"someValue (tabC) RW" }]`
```

filtering criteria is that when I am in tabA it should display both the tabA RO ,Rw values and only RO values of other tabs , same way if I am in tabB it should display both RO,RW values of tabB and only RO values of other tabs,same for the rest of the tabs . could somebody give me the logic.

Comment: Your data structure is wrong. Please update your question with correct array of objects

Comment: This is exactly the format of data that is being sent from the API

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the data structure you are talking. I assume it looks like below.

```js
const data = [
    { value: "tabAsomeValueRO (tabA) RO" }, 
    { value: "tabAsomeValueRW (tabA) RW" },
    { value: "tabBsomeValueRO (tabB) RO" }, 
    { value: "tabBsomeValueRW (tabB) RW" },
    { value: "tabCsomeValueRO (tabC) RO" }, 
    { value: "tabCsomeValueRW (tabC) RW" }
]

/**
 * convert to the following object
   {
    tabA: {
        RO: "tabAsomeValueRO",
        RW: "tabAsomeValueRW",
    },
    tabB: {
        RO: "tabBsomeValueRO",
        RW: "tabBsomeValueRW",
    },
    tabC: {
        RO: "tabCsomeValueRO",
        RW: "tabCsomeValueRW",
    }
}
 */
const regex = /([^ ]+) \(([^\)]+)\) ([^ ]+)/;
const newData = data.map(val => val.value).reduce((accum, val) => {
    const arr = regex.exec(val);
    const value = arr[1];
    const tabName = arr[2];
    const rValue = arr[3];
    if (!accum[tabName]) {
        accum[tabName] = {};
    }
    accum[tabName][rValue] = value; 
    return accum; 
}, {});

function getValue(tab) {
    return Object.keys(newData).reduce((accum, tmpTab) => {
        const tmpTabValue = newData[tmpTab];
        if (tmpTab === tab) {
            accum.push(tmpTabValue.RO); 
            accum.push(tmpTabValue.RW); 
        }
        else {
            accum.push(tmpTabValue.RO);
        }
        return accum;
    }, []);
}

console.log("tabA", getValue("tabA"));
console.log("tabB", getValue("tabB"));
console.log("tabC", getValue("tabC"));
```

Comment: please don't modify the data , as I do not have any option to modify it .

Comment: Can you explicitly specify the data structure, it is a string or ...? You can create dummy data, but with the same data structure as you described. Otherwise it is very hard for others to help you. As your object is not valid at the moment

Comment: just update, does not change any code at all, but just convert your array to the object I define previously. Have a check, and should work as expected

Comment: This solution works but you are modifying the original data, i e. removing the spaces and parentheses , The after filtering the data should contain spaces and parenthesis is there any way you can modify it ?